# Yii2: findone() syntax on multiple where condition

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I have a table ipd_charges with columns

table - ipd_charges

```
id    doctor room_category charges_cash charges_cashless
1        1          1              200            300
2        1          2              300            400
```

table - patient_admission

```
id patient_name tpa_name(if not null, equivalent to charges_cashless)
1        1        Null
2        2         1
```

table daily_ward_entry

```
id  patient_name  room_name  doctor_name charges ( from ipd charges)
1          1           1           1         200
2          2           2           1         400
```

I am trying to use this query which is failing:

```
$model = \app\models\IpdCharges::find()
         ->where(['doctor'=>$id])
         ->andwhere(['room_category'=>$this->room_name])->one();
```

Thanks. Please tell me if any more info is needed.

A help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the value of `$this->room_name`?

Comment: I am trying to pull the value of current table i.e. `'daily_ward_entry.room_name'`

Comment: You have 2 typos. It should be `where(['doctor_name' => $id])` and `andWhere...`. Is the code throwing any error?

Comment: Ok I have a typo in the question, actual column name in ipd_charges is doctor. I have updated the question. and if I am using `$this->room_name` I am getting the error - `Getting unknown property: app\controllers\DailyWardEntryController::room_name`, but if I am using `daily_ward_entry.room_name` I am getting the result `Null`

Comment: Your code looks valid. Is there any error being thrown?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your problem correctly but you can pass multiple where conditions as well in array like this ```->where(['doctor'=>$id, 'room_category'=>$this->room_name])```

Answer (score 15):

Please check below code :

```
$ipdCharges = new IpdCharges();
$ipdCharges->findOne(['doctor' => $id, 'room_category' => $this->room_name]);
```

Comment: The correct syntax is `static::findOne()`. The entire idea behind the new `ActiveRecord` in  Yii2 is that you *don't* need an instance to do queries (remember the `model()`?)

Comment: Can we add `or` condition in `findOne()`?

Comment: @Moeez I didn't `or` but try like this `['or', ['doctor' => $id, 'room_category' => $this->room_name]]` it might work.